# curl -- via proxy -- how to ignore self signed certificate

Tags: curl, proxy, ssl, certificates, https

- I can access insecure sites:

```bsh
curl -k https://self-signed.badssl.com
```

- I can access a site with `mitmproxy`:

```bsh
curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 --cacert ~/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem https://google.com
```

---

How can I combine this? I get the error when I try to access a self-signed site via `mitmproxy`:

```bsh
curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 --cacert ~/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem -k https://self-signed.badssl.com

<html>
<head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
    <p>Certificate verify failed: self signed certificate</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my bad, that was so easy. I just obviously should have told the proxy that **IT** should ignore the certificate of the end site:

```
$ ./mitmdump --ssl-insecure
```